# What's the perimeter of this poorly specified triangle?

Tags: geometry

Generalizing a puzzle from [Mind Your Decisions](https://www.youtube.com/user/MindYourDecisions), here's something that I found to be rather neat.

[image: Geometry Puzzle]

Suppose that AB$=c$, AC$=b$, and BC$=a$. What's the perimeter of $\triangle$CDE?

Clue: The coveted tick will go to the most attractive, visual proofs/arguments that don't use any additional variables! Judges decision etc.

Comment: Do you mean $BC=a$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably not something OP expects (with a lot of additional variables) but I would like to publish my idea anyway:

[image: Proposed solution]

The clue is to "build" `|AD|` and `|BE|` segments from fragments of `|AB|` and `|DE|`

(we can also use a known property of [quadrilateral circumscribing circle](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/plane-geometry/quadrilateral-circumscribing-circle) which says that `|AD| + |BE| = |AB| + |DE|`)

We can derive that:

`a + b = (|AD| + |DC|) + (|CE| + |EB|) = c + |DE| + |DC| + |EC|`

so by subtracting `c` from both sides:

`|DE| + |DC| + |EC| = a + b - c`

Answer (score 2):

Since $AB=BC=c$, and $AC=b$ we know this is an isosceles triangle (which makes the diagram a poor representation of the question). 
 This means that the point where the inscribed circle touches $AC$ (the side not equal to the others) is the midway mark.  Lets call this point $M$.

Since no guidance was given on $D$ and $E$, one can move $D$ all the way towards $M$.  To maintain the tangent, $E$ then nears $C$.  As $D$ approaches $M$, and $E$ approaches $C$, the triangle approaches an isosceles triangle whose two long sides are both $DC$ and whose short side is $0$.  Thus, the perimeter of $CDE$ is $CD+CD=2CD$.  Since $AC=c$ and $CD=CM$ is half of $AC$, we know $CD=\frac{c}{2}$.

Thus, The perimeter of $CDE=2CD=2\frac{c}{2}=c$.

Comment: This was probably correct, but the OP had actually made a typo. AB != BC, and hence, it is not an isosceles triangle.